# Is there a counterpart to NSImageNameFolder for files?

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

`NSImage` comes with a number of system images. One of them being `NSImageNameFolder` for a generic folder icon.

What about a generic image for a single file or document? There does not seem to be such a thing as `NSImageNameDocument`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
NSImage *fileImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
             iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kGenericDocumentIcon)];
```

If necessary, you may need to import `<CoreServices/CoreServices.h>`.

Comment: Nice! Swift variant: `NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFileType: NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(OSType(kGenericDocumentIcon)))`